# css background-color invisible on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I feel a bit stupid asking this but somehow the background-color of my navigation bar (ul) isn't visible (I know it's there because it is visible when my JQuery script gives it a fixed position.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;

}
#HeaderImage{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
}
#Nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    display: block;
}
.Nav{
    display: block;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
}
.NavEx{
    display: block;
    color: #c5c5c5;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    padding: 1%;
}
.Nav:hover,.NavEx:hover{
    background-color: #006500;
    color: #00ff00;
}
.FixedNav {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#Content{
    background-color: #2d5c1e;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.HomeContent{
    text-align: center;
}
#HH{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24pt;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>GIP</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Some JQuery here to make the navigation bar stay on top when scrolled beneath it.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                console.log($(window).scrollTop())
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#HeaderImage').height()) {
                    $('#Nav').addClass('FixedNav');
                }
                if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('#HeaderImage').height()) {
                    $('#Nav').removeClass('FixedNav');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <img ID="HeaderImage" src="images\WebsiteHeader.jpg" alt="headerimage" />
            <ul ID="Nav">
                <a href="Default.aspx"><li class="Nav">Home</li></a>
                <a href="About.aspx"><li class="Nav">About</li></a>
                <a href="Gastenboek.aspx"><li class="Nav">Forum</li></a>
                <a href="Contact.aspx"><li class="Nav">Contact</li></a>
                <a href="Login.aspx"><li class="NavEx">Login</li></a>
                <a href="Default.aspx"><li class="NavEx">Logout</li></a>
      </ul>
        <div id="Content">
            <h2 id="HH">Hiya.</h2>
            <p class="HomeContent">Nothing interesting here yet.</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have floated content inside of `#Nav`. Floated elements do not take up any space, therefore `#Nav` has a height of `0` so you cannot see the background color.

Use some form of a clearfix to rectify this.

- Poor man's clearfix: `overflow: hidden;`, add to element with floated content (i.e. `#Nav` in your case).
- The [Micro Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```js
//Some JQuery here to make the navigation bar stay on top when scrolled beneath it.
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#HeaderImage').height()) {
      $('#Nav').addClass('FixedNav');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('#HeaderImage').height()) {
      $('#Nav').removeClass('FixedNav');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#HeaderImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
#Nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Nav {
  display: block;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
}
.NavEx {
  display: block;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
  padding: 1%;
}
.Nav:hover,
.NavEx:hover {
  background-color: #006500;
  color: #00ff00;
}
.FixedNav {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#Content {
  background-color: #2d5c1e;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.HomeContent {
  text-align: center;
}
#HH {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <img ID="HeaderImage" src="images\WebsiteHeader.jpg" alt="headerimage" />
  <ul ID="Nav">
    <li class="Nav"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li class="Nav"><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    <li class="Nav"><a href="Gastenboek.aspx">Forum</a></li>
    <li class="Nav"><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="NavEx"><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
    <li class="NavEx"><a href="Default.aspx">Logout</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <div id="Content">
    <h2 id="HH">Hiya.</h2>
    <p class="HomeContent">Nothing interesting here yet.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Note:** You had invalid markup with the `<li>` and `<a>` so I fixed it in my example. The `<a>` should be inside of `<li>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my problem. You wouldn't believe how much time I spent trying to figure out what was wrong. I fixed the markup immediately as well, my bad. Would upvote this if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Although I advice you to take a look at your classname / id naming, you will see the background-color becomes visible when applying the following CSS Rule:

```
#Nav a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The reason is that by default the anchor tag is set by default, conflicting with the list element inside the anchor tag which is also displayed inline (note also that the HTML markup is incorrect. An `<ul>` can only contain `<li>` elements.

So to conclude your HTML should more look like:

```
<ul id="Nav">
    <li class="Nav">
        <a href="#">etc.</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a height to your #Nav.

Plus this is the correct syntax of an ul.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```